# Magento Fatal Error due to memory allocated for images

Tags: php, image, magento, fatal-error

Im getting the following error after uploading an image for a product (the other 10 uploaded are fine).

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9600001 bytes) in /home/site/public_html/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 214
```

I have tried increasing the php limit through .htacess and php.ini but still no joy.

**Update**

ok the memory is currently set to 64m (used phpinfo), i have added  php_value memory_limit 512M to .htaccess in the root directory

ive also just noticed i was only changing the sample php.ini provided (php.ini.sample) changing this to php.ini simply knocks down my site so i cannot see the effects anyway

Comment: You tried increasing. What went wrong? You didn't manage to increase? You still get similar errors no matter how much memory you allow?

Comment: ok the memory is currently set to 64m (used phpinfo), i have added  php_value memory_limit 512M to .htaccess in the root directory

ive also just noticed i was only changing the sample php.ini provided (php.ini.sample) changing this to php.ini simply knocks down my site so i cannot see the effects anyway

Comment: Like Ruddy recommended, try setting it to -1. This makes sure php can use as much memory as available... This is bad practice though... Better find out which image is causing the problem.

Comment: still nothing its almost as if its completely ignoring .htaccess

Comment: Open your .htaccess file that located in your root directory. and you can see all init configurations and your memory limit configuration. Set your memory limit like this "php_value memory_limit 256M". You can change the size whatever you want..!!

Comment: as explained this has already been set to php_value memory_limit 512M but its not having an effect and the phpinfo still tells me: memory_limit 64M

Comment: Could it be that your hosting is not using Apache? Or that the apache configuration ignores .htaccess files?

Comment: My hosting is using Apache, and this shouldnt be the case im running 5 magento sites all working seemlessly

Comment: is there a reason why i cant activate the php.ini.sample (change to php.ini) it simply knocks the whole site down and produces an arror page

Answer (score 1):

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` overrides the default PHP memory limit.

As Chris Lane stated in a similar post. (wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: I have spent the last hour chasing a problem where setting the memory limit to -1 PREVENTS any image from being uploaded. In the Magento core there is a check made before the image is attempted to be dealt with (lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php line 57) where the size of the image is compared to the available memory. It does not take into account a value of -1 meaning unlimited and throws a "Memory limit has been reached" exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. Use the [by Ruddy proposed method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295310/1857053) for increasing the php memory_limit. This could work, but please do this in a .htaccess file (so there is no difference in this setting throughout your Magento instance).
2. Find out which image is being processed. Magento resizes images for caching and this error usually is a result from an oversized image being loaded into the GD library. I once got this error when it tried to resize an image of 36000 by 36000 pixels (sigh...)

Answer (score 0):

The reason my php.ini file was causing problems is because the default sample provided was not loading the PDO mySql extensions which i resolved by using

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

then simply changing the memory limit in php.ini did the trick thankyou for the help